# Cancellation in fractions

Tags: math-mode, mathjax

This came up in Math.SE. Is there any way to produce a single cancellation across two fractions, like this?

[image]

Ideally, it should be MathJax compatible, since that's what we use over there. Unfortunately, MathJax doesn't support the `cancel` package.

Comment: I just found [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/15142) although there is no mention of how to use rules.

Comment: I suppose picture mode is not supported by MathJax either.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about MathJax, rather than TeX

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MathJax *does* provide a [`cancel` extension](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/cancel.html) that allows you to use

- `\cancel{<math>}`: 
  Strikeout `<math>` from lower left to upper right.
- `\bcancel{<math>}`:
  Strikeout `<math>` from upper left to lower right.
- `\xcancel{<math>}`:
  Strikeout `<math>` with an “X”.
- `\cancelto{<value>}{<math>}`:
  Strikeout `<math>` with an arrow going to value.

Currently, the `cancel` extension is not available/loaded by default on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com). However, it can be invoked using [`\require{cancel}`](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions.html#loading-extensions-at-run-time). Perhaps [voting in the polls on Meta.Math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3667/15142) to have it added by default might ease the use, in addition to including other basic extensions.

Here's how one would load the `cancel` extension using MathJax:

[image]

Comment: There is no need to have it added by default, you can load extensions using `\require{cancel}` I'll add a picture to your answer as It's easier than adding it in comment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the addition. I'll clear up some of my comments in the answer. And, happy birthday. :)

Comment: Just what I was hoping for. Thanks so much to both of you.